# How do I reverse-find object dependencies?

Tags: linked-data, mirror-modifier, empty

**How do I find everything referencing an object so I can update them? (i.e. mirror mods, etc.)**

I'm a newb who's gotten carried away building a house. But it's getting big and I'm trying to organize and siphon off chunks of data (walls, structure, appliances, etc.) into their own files I can just link in.

The problem is mirrors that use an archaic feature of size. I originally used the "foundation" mesh as the center point and then learned how to use empties... so now I have an empty center point I'm using for everything. But there are still mirror mods looking for the foundation, so when I copy things to a new file, the foundation keeps showing up when I just want the center point.

It would seem a dependency/reverse-dependency graph is in order, but I'm not sure where such a thing exists, and searching does not yield what I'm looking for.